Why does the order of addition/subtraction sometimes matter in MATLAB?
I have a simple function, a - b + c, whose value depends on the order of addition/subtraction:
clear; clc;

a = -1.0;
b = 0.9;
c = 0.9;

d = a - b + c;
e = a - (b - c);
f = (a - b) +  c;
g = a + c - b;

disp(['d = ',num2str(d,'%1.38f')])
disp(['e = ',num2str(e,'%1.38f')])
disp(['f = ',num2str(f,'%1.38f')])
disp(['g = ',num2str(g,'%1.38f')])
disp(['d - e = ',num2str(d-e,'%1.38f')])
disp(['d - f = ',num2str(d-f,'%1.38f')])
disp(['d - g = ',num2str(d-g,'%1.38f')])

Command Window
d = -0.99999999999999988897769753748434595764
e = -1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000
f = -0.99999999999999988897769753748434595764
g = -1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000
d - e = 0.00000000000000011102230246251565404236 
d - f = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000
d - g = 0.00000000000000011102230246251565404236

On paper, d = e = f = g = 1. However, MATLAB reports that d ~= e, d = f, and d ~= g. Here are some other observations:

If instead a = 1.0, then MATLAB reports d = e = f = 1 ~= g.
If instead b = c = 0.8, then MATLAB reports d = e = f = g = 1 (as desired).

What is happening and why?
I tried changing the parameter values to see if the problem persists.

I think this is related to so called "The Minecraft boat-drop mystery". Watch video about it with explanation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ei58gGM9Z8k

Note that double only has about 16 decimal digits of precision (52 binary digits), so printing 38 of them is not useful. eps(1) is the smallest value you can add to 1 to give you a number that is not 1.
